# Find between dates into mongo with string type data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have My data Stored like this on mongodb:

```
{ 
    "_id" : { "$oid" : "5385a437084ea4734b03374f" },
    "linea" : 1, 
    "egunak" : [ 
        { 
            "fetxa" : "2014/05/26", 
            "turnoak" : [ 
                 { 
                     "turno" : 1,
                     "ordenes" : [ 
                         { "ref" : "3CI00001" },
                         { "of" : "OF000d013" }
                     ]
                 }, 
                 { 
                     "turno" : 2, 
                     "ordenes" : [ 
                         { "ref" : "3CI00001" }, 
                         { "of" : "112-2233" }, 
                         { "ref" : "3CI0-0001" },
                         { "ref" : "666" }, 
                         { "ref" : "33" }, 
                         { "ref" : "3355" },
                         { "ref" : "345" },
                         { "ref" : "1234" } 
                     ] 
                 },
                 { 
                     "turno" : 3,
                     "ordenes" : [
                         { "ref" : "3CI00001" },
                         { "ref" : "12" }
                     ]
                 }
            ]
        }, 
        { "fetxa" : "2014/05/27" },
        {
            "fetxa" : "2014/05/28",
            "turnoak" : [
                { 
                    "turno" : 1,
                    "ordenes" : [
                        { "ref" : "3CI0-0001" },
                        { "of" : "OF200013" }
                    ]
                },
                { 
                    "turno" : 2,
                    "ordenes" : [
                        { "ref" : "3CI00001-" },
                        { "of" : "OF232233" },
                        { "of" : "OF289977" }
                    ]
                },
                { 
                    "turno" : 3,
                    "ordenes" : [
                        { "ref" : "3CI00001" },
                        { "of" : "OF200-000" },
                        { "ref" : "3CI00001" },
                        { "of" : "OF200000" },
                        { "ref" : "3CI00001" }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, 
        { "fetxa" : "2014/05/29" },
        { "fetxa" : "2014/05/30" },
        { "fetxa" : "2014/05/31" },
        { "fetxa" : "2014/06/01" }
    ]
},
{ 
    "_id" : { "$oid" : "5385a448084ea4734b033750" },
    "linea" : 2,
    "egunak" : [
        {
            "fetxa" : "2014/05/26",
            "turnoak" : [
                { 
                    "turno" : 2,
                    "ordenes" : { "ref" : "123" } 
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "fetxa" : "2014/05/27",
            "turnoak" : [
                {
                    "turno" : 1,
                    "ordenes" : [
                        { "ref" : "3CI00002" },
                        { "of" : "2OF000013" }
                    ]
                },
                { 
                    "turno" : 2,
                    "ordenes" : [
                        { "ref" : "3CI00001" },
                        { "of" : "2OF2233" },
                        { "ref" : "3CI00001" },
                        { "ref" : "999" }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "turno" : 3,
                    "ordenes" : [
                        { "ref" : "3CI00001" }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        { 
            "fetxa" : "2014/05/28",
            "turnoak" : [
                {
                    "turno" : "2",
                    "ordenes" : { "ref" : "66" }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "fetxa" : "2014/05/29",
            "turnoak" : [
                { 
                    "turno" : 1,
                    "ordenes" : [
                        { "ref" : "3CI00001" },
                        { "of" : "2OF200013" }
                    ]
                },
                { 
                    "turno" : 2,
                    "ordenes" : [
                        { "ref" : "3CI00001" },
                        { "of" : "2OF232233" },
                        { "ref" : "3CI00001" }
                    ]
                },
                { 
                    "turno" : 3,
                    "ordenes" : [
                        { "ref" : "3CI00001" },
                        { "of" : "2OF200000" },
                        { "ref" : "3CI00001" },
                        { "of" : "2OF200000" }, 
                        { "ref" : "3CI00001" }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        { "fetxa" : "2014/05/30" },
        { "fetxa" : "2014/05/31" },
        { "fetxa" : "2014/06/01" }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to find into my data between two dates but the data is stored with in string, how can I achieve that? or I need to store my data on date format?

This is my persist function on nodejs:

```
exports.save = function(req, res){
    db.open(function(err, db) {
        if(!err) {
            var data = req.body;
            var BSON = mongo.BSONPure;
            var o_id = new BSON.ObjectID(data._id);

            db.collection('test').update({'_id': o_id}, { $set :{ egunak: data.egunak } }, {safe:true, multi:false, upsert:false}, function(e, result){
                if (e) console.log(e)
                res.send((result===1)?{msg:'success'}:{msg:'error'})
            })

        } else {
            onErr(err, function(){
                console.log(err);
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Where the $set value is my JSON. How can I store the date data?

Comment: Yes you should store your dates in date format. You also do not say which dates. So which? There are dates all over this document.

Comment: I´m looking for something like SELECT * FROM Datuak WHERE egunak between '01/01/1979' and '31/12/2222'. In this case will be all of them but I´ll change it wich combo boxes. How do you persist data on mongo from node when you send data throught JSON? For example, the JSON on my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can alway use

> JSON.stringify(js_object); // this convert js Object to object in string format

before sending data, and

> JSON.parse(object_in_string_format); // this convert back the object in string format to js object.

after received the data. Read more at [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

- You should store datetime in Date type
- Then you can 'select' like the following:

  ```
  db.collection('Datuak').find(
    {"egunak.fetxa": {"$gte": new Date(1979, 1, 1), //date type here
                    "$lt": new Date(2222, 12, 31)}
    }
  )
  ```

Answer (score -2):

Though it is better you store your dates in DATE format, but if you still want a workaround you can use  Date.parse(date) function to get the value in milliseconds. I tried following in mongodb 2.4.8 and both works well

```
var d = Date.parse("March 21, 2012"); 
var d = Date.parse("2014/03/21");
```

now 'd' will contain data in milliseconds  and you can use that to find data between two dates.

Comment: How do you persist data on mongo from node when you send data throught JSON? For example, the JSON on my question.

Comment: Finding the milliseconds between two dates doesn't help when the data isn't stored as a Date in the first place.